# Generic form with angular spring

Tags: javascript, java, angularjs, database, spring

I'm planing to create generic form created dynamically with JSON data from server.

Assume a ng form, using ng repeat we populating dynamic form, based on the first set of JSON.

If the form has drop-down or radio elements there should be another call to get subset elements (textbox, radio)  to populate under the parent drop down or radio.

If drop-down changes, sub form should be added under the parent drop down.

There is no workflow using those data. Only CRUD Operations are performed.

I'm planing this to do generically from angular controller till db design level.

How the db/service design should be for making Json for parent set?

How to link the parent and sub set even sub's subset?

How to save the data and do edit operation?

Also is it better idea to save data as Json in db column?

Comment: I'm struggling to understand what you're saying. Particularly when you start trying to explain the radio box and drop-down. I wouldn't waste my time on this if it's just temporary; is there not any ideas on what columns are going to be in your tables?

Comment: I have edited my question please see if u can understand,

Comment: This show not be temporary because, requirement has around 200 attributes, thats the reason I'm thinking of saving the data as property key value pair in db kindly advice in this

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I understood your question but if you have an option to display a form from a set of forms, you can just create templates of those forms and display them on the dropdown select.

If it is a generic form template then I guess you only have to change the labels and the form names in those html templates. You can bind the values to the same model names to ng-model in the controller.

DB design depends on the nature of data you have, which you have not mentioned, so its tough to answer.

'JSON data' is the payload passed through your REST services. That has to do with how you design your response data. If its just form-templates details for the form suggested you've selected in the dropdown, then you can just pass the label names and data types for those fields.

So there will be 2 services. 
1. A GET to get the Form template labels and field definitions. 
2. A POST to submit the form.

Keep in mind that all these forms are defined at the beginning and not created on the fly. i.e you cannot create a new form-template on the fly.